R debugonce error: "Error :no more error handlers available (recursive errors?)"
After a recent upgrade to R v 4.4.0. I am getting the following error when trying to debug code in Rstudio v. 2023.06.2 ("Mountain Hydrangea") using both debugonce and debug:
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29'
In addition: Warning message:
type 29 is unimplemented in 'type2char'

Here is some example code:
> test_function <- function(x,y) {return(x+y)}
> debugonce(test_function)
> test_function(1,2)
debugging in: test_function(1, 2)
debug at #1: {
    return(x + y)
}
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29'
In addition: Warning message:
type 29 is unimplemented in 'type2char'
Browse[1]> 

It ends up getting stuck in a browse mode without any of the Rstudio helper buttons appearing and without showing the actual function code, but I can move through it via the n or Enter keys.
Any thoughts on what is causing this? Is it just that I need to update Rstudio?
System information:
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2024                        
month          04                          
day            24                          
svn rev        86474                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
nickname       Puppy Cup 


"Is it just that I need to update Rstudio?" I would do that as a first attempt. In general, after R has been updated, it is recommended (sometimes required) to update RStudio.

I am receiving the same error.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with my code.  Simply debugging with breakpoints with R 4.4.0 in RStudio with cause it.

I had the same issue with R Studio getting stuck in Browse mode, printing that Error: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29' endlessly. This occurred even by setting breakpoints, as also mentioned by Arthur in a comment. The only way I could stop the error was to use task manager to close R Studio.
Updating R Studio Desktop to 2024.4.2.764 "Chocolate Cosmos" solved it for me. Very mysterious bug in the debugger...

I had the same strange error on read.csv(). Only if I "run all", not if I just ran the one chunk.  So thanks this fixed it. Virtually every software solution includes "update to the latest version". Very rarely fixes the problem, but this time it did!

I had the same kind of issue,
myobject <- read_excel("path.xlsx", col_names = FALSE)
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error in data.frame(Name = res[[1]], Length = res[[2]], Date = dates,  : 
INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29'

Only with Quarto, while lauchning the chunk for the first time, I got this error message. It was working well the second time (without rm(list=ls()) at the begining of the code) . I updated Rstudio, and it's fixed now. Weird bug.

Specifying the sheet number helped me to resolve it:
read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet = 1)

